# If both P and Q are binary products of A and B, then P $\cong$ Q

Tags: category-theory

I am struggling to construct a proof for this statement. In order to prove an isomorphism, I need to make sure that PQ= Identity element and QP= identity element.

I first drew the commutative graphs for P and Q. ( I am not sure how to draw the graph here). From there I noticed that

x1=p1 $\circ$ f = q1 $\circ$ g such that x1: X $\rightarrow$ A , p1: P $\rightarrow$ A, f:X $\rightarrow$ P, q1: Q $\rightarrow$ A and g: X $\rightarrow$ Q.

I would greatly appreciate some tips on what to do next or to make sure I am on the right path.

Comment: One does not prove isomorphisms, one establishes/shows that certain maps are isomorphisms. What one can prove are *statements/claims* regarding various objects (in particular, morphisms). Are you familiar with the universal property of direct products?

Comment: I think so, Is it the property that takes 2 objects A and B  and constructs a new object A $\times$ B

Comment: I wouldn't say that it is the property that constructs the new object, but leaving these linguistic-philosophical matters aside, what precisely is this unversal property? Are you familiar with it?

Comment: The product of 2 sets?

Comment: By saying "familiar with it" I was referring to the universal property of direct products (it is the same in any category). Do you know what it is, this property?

Comment: No, I don't think so

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116299/discussion-between--and-elise).